# How to make two items appear next to eachother in an xs viewport with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Before I start I want to say I'm a beginner so I apologize for my messy code.

I'm still working on this so the styling is a little messy, but I'm trying to get my name (Tristen Roth) and the navbar-toggler-icon to appear next to each other on xs viewports. Currently, it puts them on two separate rows/lines vertically in the viewport. This leaves a lot of unattractive whitespaces to the right of the toggler icon and to both sides of my name.

Ideally, I want the name to appear next to the icon on the same line on xs viewports so it gets rid of the whitespace.

I've tried a bunch of things and some worked but they messed up the formatting on viewports over xs so it defeats the purpose.

```css
.row-content {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px ridge;
}

header {
  margin: 2%;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-content">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-4 col-xl-4" id="fullnavelement">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light" id="navelement">
          <div class="container pl-0  d-inline-flex" id="navcontainer">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
              <div class="navbar-nav" id="navbar-links-custom">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link px-sm-2 px-md-3 px-lg-4 px-xl-5" href="about.html">About</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-4 col-xl-4 align-self-center" id="nameobject">
        <h1 class="text-center text-nowrap">Tristen Roth</h1>
        <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
          <h5 class="text-center text-nowrap">Web Designer & Web Developer</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-4 mt-4 d-none d-md-block">
        <a class="btn btn-info text-nowrap" role="button">Contact Me</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap and try to put your code in a working snippet.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap v4.5.2

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. No critical information should be down here in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the xs from the col-xs-{n} classes and it worked:

```
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row row-content">
                <div class="col-3 col-md-4 col-xl-4" id="fullnavelement">
                    <!--Content-->
                </div>
                <!--TODO change font-->
                <div
                    class="col-9 col-md-4 col-xl-4 align-self-center"
                    id="nameobject">
                    <!--Content-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

look at this table to get an idea: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#grid-options